# Spring Kafka - Override ConsumerFactory's Deserializer Class provided as an object

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Is it possible to override the ConsumerFactory's configured deserializers if provided as an object instead of a class name in the properties? Maybe in a ContainerCustomizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; it is not possible - the only way you can provide an object is via the factory constructors or setters before creating a consumer; you cannot override these at all, not even with properties, because they are passed directly to the `KafkaConsumer` and they will be used instead of any specified in the properties.

See `ConsumerConfig.appendDeserializerToConfig()`.

You would need to use a different consumer factory if you want to override the defaults with objects.